# how to find associated model instance from another model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

post = Post.new
post.comments.build(:title=>'title1')

comment1 = post.comments.first
```

if i only get the comment1, how can i know comment1 associate to post, and post class is "Post"

Answer (score 0):

This is determined by the `foreign_key`. There will (should) be `post_id` in the comments table. You can cay `comment1.post` to get the associated Post object.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the post via `comment.post`. The associated objects will always be of class `Post` because you defined the relation like that. Anyway if you want to know which class an object has you can use `object.class` to get the Class and you can use `object.kind_of? ClassName` to verify that an Object is kind of `ClassName`.

// If you need an owner then you need to add a `user_id` field to the Comment model and add an association to it:

Comment:

```
belongs_to :user
```

User:

```
has_many :comments
```

Then you can say:

```
comment.user #This will return the owner of the comment
```

When creating the comment you need to associate the currently logged in user so you know who created it!

Comment: suppose i don't know it associate with post Model, how can i find it by program

Comment: What do you mean when you say "find it by programm"?^^

Comment: I don't know which owner have the comment,maybe there is another Model call "User", User also can build a comment without post_id, so if i don't know which one is owner, can i have some way to find out it?